# How does Xposed Framework hook methods in Android

Tags: android, security, xposed, rooted-device

I am going through Xposed framework in Android. Specifically reading blog - http://d3adend.org/blog/?p=589 for potential countermeasures and have couple of question on those line.

So when we hook a method using Xposed , framework makes that method as native and executes the code it wants to hook. So how is that in stacktrace original method is called?

```
com.example.hookdetection.DoStuff->getSecret    //This one
de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge->invokeOriginalMethodNative
de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge->handleHookedMethod
com.example.hookdetection.DoStuff->getSecret    //This one again
com.example.hookdetection.MainActivity->onCreate
android.app.Activity->performCreate
android.app.Instrumentation->callActivityOnCreate
android.app.ActivityThread->performLaunchActivity
android.app.ActivityThread->handleLaunchActivity
android.app.ActivityThread->access$800
android.app.ActivityThread$H->handleMessage
android.os.Handler->dispatchMessage
android.os.Looper->loop
android.app.ActivityThread->main
java.lang.reflect.Method->invokeNative
java.lang.reflect.Method->invoke
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller->run
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit->main
de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge->main
dalvik.system.NativeStart->main
```

Also why does it come twice in the stacktrace. I want to understand the order in which they are executed.

Is the actual method even run? Since the hooked method code executes it would not ideally execute the original method code. So how can we possible add a stracktrace detection mechanism in the same method knowing it would be replaced.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Xposed inner workings aren't easy to understand if you aren't comfortable with low level code and android kernel. To make it short, when you open an app on your Android device, there is a master process called Zygote that will spawn it as its child process.

The purpose of Xposed is to be able to control Zygote and detect whenever a process is about to be spawned, so that someone is able to hook methods by replacing their definitions before any calls are made to them.

You have a lot of control by using Xposed, you can replace the entire method body, so the original code never get called or you can use beforeCall and afterCall hooks which is basically an usage of the trampoline technique (A C++ example below)

[image: Trampoline Hook Technique (C++)]

As you can see when a method is called it doesn't directly go to the original code but to an injected code block where someone can do anything he wants (Dump, Change parameters, etc) then it will jump back to the genuine code. You can also do this after the genuine code, so you get the method output. Xposed implements this by using **beforeHookedMethod** and **afterHookedMethod**.

Adding a stacktrace detection mechanism won't help at all. You will call Java methods to get the actual stacktrace. It can be defeated easily by hooking the getStacktrace method, saving a valid genuine stacktrace, then when ever getStackTrace is called and contains Xposed methods, return the previously saved genuine stacktrace.

Your best bet is to rely on Native code to detect it, but even then any determined and experimented hacker with full device control can manage to defeat it eventually.

Comment: can you explain this part "This extended startup process adds an additional jar to the classpath and calls methods from there at certain places" its from the xposed tutorial. https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

To add to above points when you call `XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod` the callback can either be -

1. [XC_MethodHook](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.html) : Callback class for method hooks. Usually, anonymous subclasses of this class are created which override `beforeHookedMethod(XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam)` and/or `afterHookedMethod(XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam)`.
2. [XC_MethodReplacement](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodReplacement.html) : A special case of XC_MethodHook which completely replaces the original method.

1st one just provides you the hooks to execute methods before and after original method where as 2nd one replaces it completely. Eg - [Xposed example on github](https://github.com/aniket91/FlashLightXPModule)

Couple of posts I have written -

[Creating a new Xposed module in Android](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2017/03/creating-new-xposed-module-in-android.html)

[Installing Xposed Framework on Android devices](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2017/03/installing-xposed-framework-on-android.html)